# Unity global menu options disabled for certain applications

Tags: unity, appmenu

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, and am also using the Gnome 3.10 staging, next, etc. ppas. I have Cinnamon, Gnome Shell and Unity environments installed. All the environments and applications work fine.

However, there is a slight nuisance with the Unity global application menus for certain applications. For example, the global menu options are disabled (grayed out) for say gedit. Again, the menu options work properly for a few other applications.

Any suggestions to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: No attached picture?

Comment: Yeah been trying to upload the picture, but it fails.

Comment: Just include the imgur.com link in your question if that is possible.